# Solana/Rust minting error: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x3

Tags: error

I wanted to test using Rust to create my own token on the Solana network. I have created a wallet holding .07248 SOL I then used rust to create my new Token ID and Token Address.  However, when I use the following command to create fresh tokens,

spl-token mint 5000000000 I get the following error:

RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x3 [5 log messages]

Given that I think I have everything I need to correctly execute this command, I'm not sure what to make of this issue. Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

That error 0x3 corresponds to MintMismatch, which means that the destination account for the tokens was not actually a token account for your mint.

Codes for the errors are available at:https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/cd8d79a2b4aa4f90c02514d762ab21023449b6cb/token/program/src/error.rs#L22

To hold the newly minted tokens, you must first register a token account. To create the token account and mint the tokens into it, you can follow all the instructions in the documents: https://spl.solana.com/token#example-creating-your-own-fungible-token